# Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

i have already tested latest version of kotlin **1.8.20-Beta** ,**1.8.10** and **1.7.10** also my app breaks.

1. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0
2. i leady added a jetifier in android.enableJetifier=true
3. Android studio is updated
   my build.gradle file is?

   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
   apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
   apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

   android {
   compileSdkVersion 33
   ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

   ```
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.ahmadpro.tplayer"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
   ```

   }

   dependencies {
   implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
   implementation("com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1")
   }

Comment: try `cd \android` then  `.\gradlew clean` and then `.\gradlew build` . after that `flutter run` again

Comment: can you please show the android level build.gradle